# Deploy Laravel Vue Error npm run production

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ubuntu

i just ran laravel vue on vps ubuntu 22, but i encountered this error when npm run production. Why?

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../pages/admin/index' in '/var/www/mydomain.com/html/resources/js/router'
Did you miss the leading dot in 'resolve.extensions'? Did you mean '[".*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]' instead of '["*",".wasm",".mjs",".js",".jsx",".json",".vue"]'?
```

this is my admin router

```
const nameRoute = '/admin';
const routesAdmin =  [
    {
        name: 'admin',
        path: nameRoute,
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "admin" */ '../pages/admin/index'),
        children: [
            {
                name: 'admin.dashboard',
                path: `${ nameRoute }/dashboard`,
                component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "admin/dashboard" */ '../pages/admin/pages/dashboard'),
                meta: {
                    title: `Dashboard | ${process.env.MIX_APP_NAME}`,
                    auth: true
                },
            },
        ]
    },
];

export default routesAdmin
```

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/bootstrap.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.sass', 'public/css', {
        implementation: require('node-sass')
    }).vue({
        compileOptions: {
            isCustomElement: (tag) => tag === 'admin-table'
        }
    })
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            chunkFilename: 'bundles/[name].js',
        }
    });
```

When I run on windows it runs smoothly.
do I need to add vue extension configuration in nginx?